# Force SWT Text filed to use minimum number of characters

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I need a SWT text filed for a user name and it must use minimum 5 and maximum 20 characters.
It's easy to restrict the upper bound with setTextLimit(20) but I didn't find a similar method for the lower bound.

Probably I can modify a listener for my object and check the length of the string and if it's less then 5 show a popup message but it looks too complicated and maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Does anybody know an easy way to force SWT Text fields to use certain number of characters?

Comment: `setTextLimit(int)` prevents entering more characters. When the limit is reached, entering more characters will be ignored. Do you want to prevent deletion of existing characters? Otherwise, as long as the minimum is not yet reached, disable the OK button and show a non-blocking warning if there is at least one character but less than the minimum of characters.

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way. You would have to use a modify listener.